# Python Pandas - Create a new df column based on matching criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to create a new column in my pandas data frame(df). The value for each row in this column (call it column_new) needs to look at a reference column (column_ref) that already exists in the data frame. I used the unique values in column_ref and assigned them as keys in a dictionary, d:

```
d = {'column_ref_value1': 'a',
     'column_ref_value2': 'b', 
     'column_ref_value3': 'c',}
```

The values in dict(d) are values that I want to assign to to column_new in my data frame. Here is what I tried to no avail:

```
for i in df['column_ref']:
    for k, v in d.items(): 
        if k == i:
            df['column_new'] = v
```

When I call my df I am seeing column_new populated with value 'c' in every row, and I am not sure why. I'm guessing my issue has to do with improper iterating through a pandas dataframe or series.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `df['column_new'] = df['column_ref'].map(d)` do what you want?

Comment: Oh god, yes! That was so simple. Thank you! I'm going to read a books worth of info on .map() right now. What other need to know functions would you put in the same ballpark as .map()?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df['column_new'] = df.replace({'column_ref': d})
```